# How to prompt for argument and than run the program with the argument

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, hamster

I am not sure if is my question clear enough so here is some explanation what I am trying to achieve.

I need to create custom shortcut to run hamster (time tracker) to track new activity. The command is:

`$ hamster start <activity name>`

so I want to press the hotkey ( <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> ) and then want to be prompted for activity name. Then the text I will enter will be used in the command

`$ hamster start <my entered text>`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you run it in a terminal window? I think not, looking at your question, but one of the answers made me wonder.

Comment: I assumed that it should not run in a terminal, since it should be called from a keyboard shortcut...

Comment: In case someone will come across looking for this hamster feature, here is my [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/721180/why-can-not-the-bash-script-file-run-by-shortcut-get-the-content-of-a-file) about the same script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would something like

```
hamster start "$(zenity --entry)"
```

work for you?

Comment: This solutions works, but I had to put it into file and place it into `/usr/local/bin`. Still. It works. My next step will by to try adding auto-complete feature with history probably using [YAD](https://code.google.com/p/yad/)

Comment: In principle you don't need it there, any other folder in your $PATH is valid. And in principle it's better to add a folder in your own personal $PATH then a script to a system folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get a script that will prompt you for the activity name you can use the following code

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter the activity name"
read activity

hamster start $activity
```

when you run the script, you will be prompted with the message "Please enter the activity name". once you type your activity name and press enter, it will run `hamster start activity`. you can place this script in `/usr/local/bin` for easy access. Basically if you name it "myscript" and place it in that folder, you can run the script just by running `myscript`. remember to make it an executable first.

Comment: This won't work from a shortcut, only if it runs from a terminal window, which seems not the case...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is using hamster and will find this feature handy this is my current working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/usr/local/bin/hamster-log
last=$(<$file)
activity=$(zenity --entry --title "Enter new activity name" --text "New activity name:" --entry-text "$last")
hamster start "$activity"
if [ ! -z "$activity" ]; then
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "$activity" > "$file"
    fi
fi
```

It is placed in `/usr/local/bin/` folder. And in the same folder is file hamster-log with permissions 777. I am using Shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and to run this script and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to stop the activity (command `hamster stop`). When I will have more time I will keep working on this and updating the code. There are few more features I would like to add.

Comment: Just a suggestion, using `$()` is usually preferred to `\`\`` to run subshells. Also `$activity` in `hamster start $activity` will break the command if containing whitespace, so if that's a possibility it would be better to enclose it in double quotes: `hamster start "$activity"`.