# Why can not the Bash script file run by shortcut get the content of a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shortcut-keys

I have a script that starts a new activity for `hamster` (activity tracker). This is my current script:

```bsh
ACTIVITY=`zenity --entry --title "Enter new activity name" --text "New activity name:"`
hamster start $ACTIVITY
```

The problem is I would like the script to remember the last task so I can just run it with <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of typing the name again. I want it to store the name of it in file. Currently I have made the file manually: `/usr/local/bin/hamster-log`.

My script so far is the following:

```bsh
file=/usr/local/bin/hamster-log
last=$(<$file)
activity=$(zenity --entry --title "Enter new activity name" --text "New activity name:" --entry-text "$last")
hamster start "$activity"
if [ ! -z "$activity" ]; then
    destdir=/some/directory/path/filename
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "$activity" > "$file"
    fi
fi
```

The weird thing is when I run the script from terminal, it reads the file's content properly, but when I run it using a shortcut it doesn't read the file.

I have set the file's permissions to `777`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're calling the script in the custom shortcut but there are two possibilities:

- You're calling an interpreter (e.g. `sh /path/to/script`): then you're calling `sh` or an incompatible shell: command substitutions such as `$(<file)` are replaced with the content of `file` only in Bash or compatible shells, so you may be calling an incompatible shell;
- You're calling the script (e.g. `/path/to/script`): then the script doesn't have a shebang at the top.

So either:

- If the first one, call the right interpreter (`bash /path/to/script`);
- If the second one, add a shebang at the top of the script (`#!/bin/bash`).

Alternatively do something ugly (but POSIX and portable) such as:

```bsh
last=$(cat "$file")
```

Comment: Thanks. You are my hero. I have spent a lot of time trying different ways. BTW I was using the second way of calling the script.

Comment: @Posuk13 Yeah it was either one or the other, so I posted both. I kind of suspected it since you didn't have a shebang in the script you posted. Glad that it helped.